# Error when scrapin No. with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to capture the time of "Rolling" but it doesn't work.
Tried different methods, looked up on the in internet but still can't figure out what's wrong. Please help

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_format = "https://csgoempire.com/"
get_url = requests.get(url_format).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_url, 'lxml')
frame = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'wheel__item wheel__mask absolute w-full h-full top-0 left-0 z-10 wheel__item--visible')

for rezult in frame:
    time = rezult.find('div', class_ = 'text-2xl font-bold font-numeric')
    print(time)
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url_format = "https://csgoempire.com/"
get_url = requests.get(url_format).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_url, 'lxml')
frame = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'wheel__item')

for rezult in frame:
    time = rezult.find('div', class_ = 'text-2xl')
    print(time)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?  What happens when you run it?  What is the error?  Please include the full traceback error (if applicable)

Comment: it doesn't give error, just a blank output

Answer (score 1):

This page you are scraping "https://csgoempire.com/" does not contain any div with that class. So you are not seeing any results.
It seems that much of this page is generated via javascript. BS4 does not process javascript.

You will need to implement a 'client' to properly work with javascript. Please see this article, as I think it will have a lot of the building blocks you are looking for:
https://pythonprogramming.net/javascript-dynamic-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/

Comment: I used pyqt5 instead of pyqt4 because it was depricated. I tried an alternative but now i get this error at line 14 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uset/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    client_response = Client(url)
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'mainFrame'`
https://dpaste.org/4V1ta - here is the code

Comment: @pogo it seems you are trying to overload the class with your own Client class. However the QWebPage class doesnt provide any interface called mainFrame.  You can see the documentation for it here: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView.html      I think you can just call self.load() directly it looks like.